# I'm a ruby on rails developer and I don't like using jquery-ui. Am I wrong?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, jquery-ui

I use jquery all the time and couldn't build a great website without it. But I'm learning to really dislike jquery-ui.

On applications that I've seen use jquery-ui, I feel that there's too much javascript in the client. I've also seen situations where people attach jquery code to jquery-ui widgets that results in multiple events firing when a user clicks a button.

Moreover, I feel like almost all the features you get with jquery-ui you can build with plain divs and showing/hiding/animating elements using plain jquery.

In the end, I think it results in too much going on in the browser, is difficult to automate testing for, is harder to debug and really isn't needed that often anyway.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of jquery UI either. Maybe try other widget libraries?

Comment: This should be migrated to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @marcin - I prefer just using jquery and html/css. Others tell me we should be using jquery-ui because it gives a lot of functionality quickly.

Comment: I've found that *Insert framework here* features can be written using *insert language the framework is based on here*. You only need to use jquery-ui if your using most the features like datepicker and autocompelte AND it saves you time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are many who would agree testability (particularly in a cross-browser manner) is a real problem.

With regards to it being too much - there are other JS libraries and frameworks that are usable in the place of jquery-ui.

If anybody has any recommended frameworks they consider "lighter" than jquery-ui that provide similar widgets, I'd love to hear about them and will note them here.

It's important to remember that jquery-ui and jquery are split for a reason.  Jquery-ui gives you lots of nice little widgets which aim to satisfy a bunch of common use cases.  Jquery exists to do what it does better than any other library I've seen: match and manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure there is a lot going on, and used in the wrong hands you could probably end up with too much going on for no real reason.

For all the simple show/hiding modals etc... then if you are concerned with too much going on, then write it yourself.

The jQuery UI is just a nice "In the box" framework for doing things which come with nice styling and have a community behind it.

Answer (score -1):

Full-blown jQuery UI minified is 206kB, that's a lot of JS.

However, do note that if you remove everything except the core, you are left with only 25kB. You can customize your jQuery UI package here http://jqueryui.com/download.

If you think that a customized jQueryu UI package is still too big for your needs, then a microJS framework ( http://microjs.com/ ) can be a lightweight alternative.

Comment: I frequently use jQuery UI core without the rest of jQuery UI. I like being able to package up some UI stuff in widgets that integrate fairly well with the rest of jQuery, and jQuery UI is good for that even without the "in-the-box" widgets.